# Plane ticket fees

Tags: airlines, fees-and-charges

I was going to buy a ticket in Cebu Pacific and in the first page where you select just seat, seat + luggage or seat + luggage + meals I selected seat + 20Kg luggage. I checked the fare information and this is what it said:

[image: Information]

Which said that fees and taxes are included

Then at the bottom of the page I saw the total: 21.531PHP
[image: First Total]

When I clicked on next to add the passenger information. The price was up by 2000PHP I looked the information about the price and this is what they show:

[image: Total 2]

Are the charging me fees and taxes twice or are they different taxes and fees involved in a plane ticket?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common misleading trick on behalf of booking websites, where they show one price all the way up to the payment screen, and *then* add a mysterious "tax" or "booking fee".

So the answer is that, **yes**, there are additional taxes to be paid on each flight, but the booking website chooses not to show them until the last moment.

Comment: A common practice for low cost airlines usually. Super annoying... But those guys are usually fighting for every penny so they are extremely desperate to hide any additional cost to show up first (when sorting by price) on a given journey.

Comment: Bottom line it is the consumer that drives this method of pricing.  Everyone blames the airlines for being greedy, but it is our own greed searching for the cheapest deal that creates the need for this style marketing.

Comment: @Tom while is true that usually people try to find the best deal (best deal not always is the cheaper price), I don't think that's a bad thing. What is bad is companies trying to hide stuff from clients (For example I chose no meals, but by default in the next page it has added the meals) I don't think that's excusable.

Comment: @SERPRO - Did the next page give you the option to uncheck the meal portion? If so, then they aren't hiding anything, but simply being a persistent sales person. Does not a car dealer try to sell you more options on your car?  Does not a grocery store lure you in with sale prices because they know you will buy more once you are there.  Its called marketing and it is crafted based on the way people shop.

Comment: @Tom If I selected no meal, I don't see why they add it anyway. Apart from that look at this image and tell me if think is clear the link to remove the meal (Yes is that text sayin "no thanks") and by the way.. that information is hidden by default. you need to expand the food menu to see that. http://imgur.com/qzj8fPi